# Apply dd/mm/yyyy format to route via regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to have one of my controller actions pick up requests for URLs like this:

```
/Traveller/Book/28/01/2015
/Traveller/Book/01/02/2015
... etc ...
```

So I've written a `Route` attribute for my controller action like so:

```
[Route(@"Traveller/Book/{date:regex(^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$)}")]
public ActionResult Book(string date, TravellerBookingViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...
}
```

I also made my application look at the `Route` attributes by adding the following to the `RegisterRoutes` method in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Despite taking these steps, my application still doesn't route requests for the above example URLs to my controller action, and instead returns a 404. I'm confused as to why this is as the regular expression seems to match when I run it through any regular expression tools.

Edit: It's probably also worth noting that changing the `Route` attribute to:

```
[Route(@"Traveller/Book/test")]
```

Also doesn't work when I make a request to `/Traveller/Book/test`.

Comment: I think it takes your date for 3 different objects. Can you specify dates without separators? or with something that don't have special meaning? like 01_02_2015. `Traveller/Book/test` doesn't work with or without regex?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NadiaChibrikova, but check my edit. It seems the application is ignoring *any* `Route` attribute I use :/

Comment: I think you should escape slashes in your regex so : "\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$"

Comment: No need, I prefixed the string with `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Slash is used to separate url segments, which means one single segment can't contain slash unless they are encoded (`%2f`).

You can change your date format to dd-mm-yyyy and use

```
date:regex(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}
```

Also looking into `System.Web.Routing` you can tell that route values are not URL encoded using HttpUtility.UrlEncode(var) but are escaped with Uri.EscapeUriString(var).

Comment: Sebastian, may you take a look to this question? is about a similar issue where the datetime, although encoded, is passing as null to the controller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442368/routing-datetime-parameter-passing-as-null-empty